# How to change location with Maven Dependency Plugin?

Tags: maven, build, maven-dependency-plugin

I need to copy some resources from an artifact to a particular place.
I need to change the location without flatting it.

For example:

```
my-res-artifact
\
 someroot/subdir1/
 + myres1.dat
 + myres2.dat       
 \ 
  subdir12
  + myres3.dat
```

I want to copy this into `subdir1` directory, but remove the `someroot` root directory. This doesn't work with the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-additional-resources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeGroupIds>com.example</includeGroupIds>
                <includeArtifactIds>my-res-artifact</includeArtifactIds>
                <includes>someroot/subdir1/**</includes>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The directory structure `someroot/subdir1/` is preserved.

Comment: Why would you like to do such thing? Spring Boot works like that. Why do you need to copy resources ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have a good reason, which is out of the score of this question. I can change the example as well.

Comment: No they are not out of scope cause they are important that goal you want to achieve....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file names can be changed by a File Mapper.

The trick works for whole locations, too:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-additional-resources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeGroupIds>com.example</includeGroupIds>
                <includeArtifactIds>my-res-artifact</includeArtifactIds>
                <includes>someroot/subdir1/**</includes>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <fileMappers>
                    <fileMapper implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.RegExpFileMapper">
                        <pattern>someroot/subdir1</pattern>
                        <replacement>subdir1</replacement>
                    </fileMapper>
                </fileMappers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```